# Why does my keyboard sometimes not produce the right symbols?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard

I have Windows 7 Japanese Version on Fujitsu monitor computer- The keyboard is mostly a normal QWERTY with extra keys for Japanese Input. At the moment it is fine except that the key (_) next to the left Shift key in direct entry to Chrome produces a yen symbol which copies as the correct back slash. However sometimes on some webpages it produces erroneous symbols on screen- I trying to fill in a "@" from the key left of the "P2" and I don't remember the key's output however the only way to produce it was Shift+2- the website didn't accept either wrong output or visually. Sometimes the keyboard gives much more erratic output. My wife insists on vaccuuming the keyboard but it was fine in other circumstances before the erratic output. What could be wrong?  [image: Keyboard Front]

[image: Monitor Computer]

[image: Keyboard reverse side]

Comment: What is a Fujitsu Monitor Computer? What keyboard do you actually have? Maybe include a picture. What actually is working or not working? As for the Slash/Backslash that's the normal behavior (or at least was) if you change the Locale of your system to Japanese. As an example you would see that if you run a normal installation program.

Comment: Did you check your keyboard layout?

Comment: What do you mean by keyboard layout- what is written on the keys- it is mostly normal- following what is on the keys- most of the time.

Comment: Except the Google Chrome, is the keyboard input working normally? For example, in Notepad or in Word or in another web browser.

Comment: Works oddly sometimes and only symbols for some websites.

Comment: I just had the problem using Chrome in Live.com. The @ produced [ and shift 2 gives @.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> giving `@` is likely the English setting and you want something else.

Check if you have this icon in the tray. If so, click it and select the correct language that matches your keyboard. (It may show different languages on your PC of course)

[image: Language setting]

You might have accidentally changed it by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (on Windows 10, might be different on other OS).

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard layout is a Japanese layout. This wiki section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Japanese have some related background about the layout.

Because symbols placement in the layout is different from keyboards from other part of the world, so when improperly configured it might yield some unexpected input. You can try to see if the keyboard come with a driver and install it, or follow this instruction https://txcom2003.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/change-keyboard-layout-english-to-japanese/ to change your keyboard driver to a matched one.

Comment: The symbol output is usually correct for the the Japanese layout- it is a Japanese keyboard- the issue is a known problem for Chrome however the solutions are many.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure that whether these are definitive solutions since the problem hasn't reoccurred but they are the ones listed on Google Forums

click on chrome anywhere to focus the window, then press Alt+Shift once 
press Ctrl+Shift once
I click on the blue hammer thing on the right of the address bar.

Then i click option

Then i click fonts and languages settings

I used english keyboard so i clicked Western Macintosh next to the Default Decoding

ttps://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/3hii4fN6w7A

Answer (score -1):

Hmmm, maybe my suggestion is strange but try to press strg and left shift. I cannot say that it is 100% the right thing but I had smth similar to what you have described.

Comment: What is “strg”?

Comment: "Control" button